# Is defining a constant within a for-loop possible in Swift?

Tags: swift, for-loop, variables, constants

Just beginning to learn Swift and stumbled across the following code in a book:

```
for i in 0..<n {
    let x = start + delta * Double(i)
    result += [fn(x)]
}
return result
```

What puzzles me is, that x seems to be defined as a constant, but within a for loop, which should not be possible as it changes its value.

I was expecting something like:

```
for i in 0..<n {
    var x = start + delta * Double(i)
    result += [fn(x)]
}
return result
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> … as it changes its value.

It does not change the value, the local constant is (re)created in each iteration and thrown away in the closing brace line.

It changes the value therefore it must be a `var`iable with this syntax where it's declared **before** the loop

```
var x : Double
for i in 0..<n {
    x = start + delta * Double(i)
    result += [fn(x)]
}
return result
```

Comment: Not unlike how `let` constants within a function as constant for the life time of that particular _call_ to that function. It's not constant for the function as a whole, and differs from one call to the next.

Comment: Thank you both. So as this local constant only lives for the time of this particular call, it would be possible to declare a constant x for each and every new call like it has been in the example?

Comment: Yes, the first example is perfectly fine. If it was not, the compiler would complain.

Comment: The key point is that any time you enter a pair of braces, you are entering a new level of scope. Any variables or constants defined inside those braces only exist inside that scope. A for loop enters and then exits the scope of the braces on each iteration of the loop, and so local vars/constants defined inside the braces get discarded on exit of each iteration and then recreated on the next iteration. That's also true of if statements, while statements, closures, and ANY situation where your code is enclosed in braces.